# discord.py check if it's the right server or guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm trying to do a check on which server the command was called from so i can send different responses to different servers

i wanted something like this but i don't know how to achieve it

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  #    get the server's id in which the message was sent
  guild = discord.guild
  #    one of my server's id
  server1_ID = bot.get_guild(865307645434658856)

  if guild == server1_ID:
    if message.content.startswith('!Ping Roles'):
      embedVar = discord.Embed(
        title="Ping Roles", 
        description="", 
        color=discord.Color.blue(),
        )

      await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.guild` is the whole module, you want to get an instance of `discord.Guild`

```py
guild = message.guild
server1 = bot.get_guild(865307645434658856)

if guild == server1:
    ...
```